# Get news headlines from nu.nl in a text file

Tags: linux, bash, text, html

I'd like to have the news headlines of nu.nl in a text file, so that I can use them in one of my bash scripts. I want to extract these headlines with a bash script as well.

I have added a screenshot of nu.nl's homepage of today (https://i.stack.imgur.com/gS2mp.png). For example, I'd like to have in a textfile:

```
"Ook met Grieks referendum houdt Eurogroep vandaag nog overleg <br/>
Koeweit pakt verdachten van aanslag op <br/>
Ruim 4 op de 5 boetes voor te hard rijden <br/>
... et cetera"
```

I am programming bash scripts on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.16.0-41-generic x86_64)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an XML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...) to parse one or more of its [rss feeds](http://www.nu.nl/rss.html):

```
wget -O - http://www.nu.nl/rss/Algemeen 2>/dev/null | xmlstarlet sel -t -v /rss/channel/item/title | sed 's|$| <br/>|'
```

Output:

```
Lange rijen voor pinautomaten Griekenland <br/>
A9 afgesloten vanwege groot ongeval <br/>
'Schutter aanslag Sousse was een Tunesiër' <br/>
Koning, premier en minister Hennis bij Veteranendag in Den Haag <br/>
'Koeweit pakt verdachten van aanslag op' <br/>
Ruim 4 op de 5 boetes zijn voor te hard rijden <br/>
Witte Huis verlicht met regenboogkleuren om homohuwelijk VS <br/>
'Te veel leraren staan zonder diploma voor de klas' <br/>
Vliegtuig met Nederlandse toeristen uit Tunesië geland op Schiphol <br/>
Ernstige mishandeling en aanhoudingen bij TT Assen <br/>
```