# How do I pull some information from a website via bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to get the specific information from this site BTC value:

foxbit.com.br

I would just like to take the value of the BTC , but with WGET and CURL can not , because the value of the page is not static .

Do this is possible?

Comment: Use wget/curl and an XML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint, ...).

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31087448/3776858

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can go about doing such things:

1. Load the page and see that the values load shorly after the page. This indicates that it's updated by a separate ajax request.
2. Open the Chrome developer console and look through the small handful of requested xhr resources to see which document it comes from.
3. Right click the request and copy as cURL.

You get some monstrosity like this:

```
curl 'http://www.foxbit.com.br/cdn-cgi/pe/bag2?r\[\]=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.blinktrade.com%2Fapi%2Fv1%2FBRL%2Fticker%3Fcallback%3DjQuery21109214518333319575_1448214593730%26crypto_currency%3DBTC%26_%3D1448214593731' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch' -H 'PE-Token: 136c4c7c7a1e6a4bea75c61a93655067d5752459-1448214593-1800' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,no;q=0.6,nb;q=0.4' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64) AppleWebKit/530.00 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.0.0 Safari/530.00' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Referer: http://www.foxbit.com.br/' -H 'Cookie: __cfduid=d069fe8cecbd20bd0d09a5c04fbc398601448214586; _gat=1; _ga=GA1.3.1862709458.1448214588' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --compressed
```

However, the URL clearly indicates that it just fetches from some other API, so we decode that URL and get:

```
https://api.blinktrade.com/api/v1/BRL/ticker?callback=jQuery21109214518333319575_1448214593730&crypto_currency=BTC&_=1448214593731
```

And we can drop the parameters that seem irrelevant and see what we get now:

```
$ curl 'https://api.blinktrade.com/api/v1/BRL/ticker?crypto_currency=BTC'
{"high": 1272.5, "vol": 50.77552492, "buy": 1238.51, "last": 1244.0, "low": 1238.13, "pair": "BTCBRL", "sell": 1243.99, "vol_brl": 63522.33386051}
```

Nice clean JSON. We can now easily make a command fetching and picking out the value we're interested in with the json tool `jq`:

```
$ curl -s 'https://api.blinktrade.com/api/v1/BRL/ticker?crypto_currency=BTC' | 
    jq '.last'
1244
```